# Swagger-UI Symfony NelmioAPiDoc add multiple responseType options

Tags: symfony, swagger-ui, nelmioapidocbundle

I am looking for a way to add multiple response types to swagger-ui implemented through NelmioAPiDoc

[image]

I would like the option for image/jpeg as a response type I have the code to work in the controller to set the body to the image even if the response type still say's application/json but my goal is if 'application/json' is selected it returns the url of image in json format, but if 'image/jpeg' is selected it returns the image to the body. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
 /**
 * @Security("is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')")
 *
 * @Route("/api/airs/renderframe", name="get_airs_frame", methods={"GET"})
 *
 * @SWG\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="Returns json image url from paramaters",
 * )
 * @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="imageHost",
 *     in="query",
 *     type="string",
 *     description="image host"
 * )
 * @SWG\Parameter(
 *     name="imagePath",
 *     in="query",
 *     type="string",
 *     description="image path"
 * )
 *
```

I have also tried adding this to the top of my class but still have the one drop down option

```
 /**
 *  @SWG\Swagger(
 *               schemes={"http"},
 *               produces={"image/jpeg","application/json"},
 *               consumes={"application/json"}
 *  )
 */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working by putting the produces{} inside the @SWG\Get() but the response type is not in the request as a parameter need to figure out how to access the value now

```
    /**
 * @Security("is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')")
 *
 * @Route("/api/airs/renderframe", name="get_airs_frame", methods={"GET"})
 *
 * @SWG\Get(
 *     produces={"application/xml", "application/json"},
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="imageHost",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="string",
 *         description="image host"
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="imagePath",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="string",
 *         description="image path"
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="resource",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="string",
 *         default="renderframe/serveframe",
 *         description="Render picture in frame"
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="maxSize",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="integer",
 *         description="image max Size"
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="inchesWidth",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="integer",
 *         description="image inches WIdth"
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *         name="inchesHeight",
 *         in="query",
 *         type="integer",
 *         description="image inches Height"
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Response(
 *         response=200,
 *         description="Returns json image url from paramaters",
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\Tag(name="Render picture in frame")
 * )
```